# allow only numbers and slash in textbox vba

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

The following code allows only numbers to be typed in `TextBox1`. But `TextBox1` is for insertion of history (Date) and I want to with format "0000/00/00". How can I exclude "/" from `IsNumeric` In the error message?

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
   MsgBox "only numbers allowed"
   With TextBox1
  .SetFocus
  .SelStart = 0
  .SelLength = Len(.Text)
   End With
End If
Dim strTemp As String
If TextBox1.TextLength = 8 Then
  Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "0000/00/00")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should better use *IsDate* to check if the value typed in `Textbox1` is a date or not, and then you can change the format to `yyyy\mm\dd` or whatever your needs are.

Comment: What do you mean with _history(Date)_? Are you talking about dates like 10.07.1523?

Comment: I think `IsDate` is just for the history of the Gregorian calendar. For non-Gregorian calendar dates? – @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: Sorry, could you please post an example of a non-gregorian calendar date? Maybe then you should loop each character of the string and check if it's a number or ar `\`

Comment: Hi _Foxfire And Burns And Burns_!
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar) and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) for non-gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event (`KeyPress` is probably easier to use) to manage which characters can be added.

In your case above, you must control the character range based on the length of the string in the field.

- First character must be a digit (check for ascii `0` to `9`)
- Second character can be a digit or a `\`
- If the second character is a digit, then append a `\` for them!

This pattern repeats for the next digit block. The final digit block could be 2 or 4 digits.

*Edit*: I have my blocks in the reverse order from the OP. The first block would only accept 4 digits followed by the `\` and the other two digit blocks as described above. But the concept is still the same, use the `Key*` event to control what can be entered based on what string is already in the TextBox.

Don't enable the "OK" button unless the string is complete. This means not until in the third digit block, and then only if there are 2 or 4 digits in the digit block.

At all times, the "Cancel" button is enabled, so they can escape any time they want. The above approach does not guarantee a valid date (if that is what you want) so additional checks are required before enabling the "OK" button.

Using the above approach, and not allowing the user to accept an invalid number means less error checking in your other code!

Of course, you could also use a DateTimePicker!

Comment: Hello dear friend AJD! As far as i found out, Your response, for this code, is not applicable. Because after the date is completed, the character "/" is automatically added, and an error message is displayed at this time. -@AJD

Comment: @FirstLast: The point of this concept is that you control which characters get added, so don't add the final "\".